AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_restore_group' | celery
I am using a chord with a group as first argument and a task as for the callback. I am dispatching this chord from a celery task. The error that I am getting is
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 488, in on_chord_part_return
    header_result = GroupResult.restore(gid)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 960, in restore
    return backend.restore_group(id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 656, in restore_group
    meta = self.get_group_meta(group_id, cache=cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 649, in get_group_meta
    meta = self._restore_group(group_id)

Structure is something similar to this
@CELERY.task(bind=True, name='abcd')
def abcd():
   jobs = chord(group(
        CELERY.signature('xyz',kwargs={}) for x in y),
        CELERY.signature('ijk',immutable=True, kwargs = {}))
    result = jobs.apply_async(queue="ocr-queue2"})
    result.save()

@CELERY.task(bind=True, name='xyz')
def xyz(self, a,b):
    try:
       return True
    except Exception:
       return False

@CELERY.task(bind=True, name='ijk')
def ijk(self, a,b):
    try:
       return True
    except Exception:
       return False


This is failing intermittently with the error attached above. Also to note I have enabled redis backend for the celery. Can someone suggest if there is anything wrong with this.

So what is your result backend? This error is related to your result backend it seems. Check your result backend setting.

its a normal redis_url,  haven't put any settings on it.
CELERY = Celery('celery_tasks',
backend=REDIS_URL,
broker=BROKER_URL)

I think you should put a break on a line where celery configuration is done and check what exactly what self.backend is - basically verify that the backend of the Celery object is what you expect it to be.
